# Forelse loop inside a <div> tag

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a container with a list of images and attributes, but when I add a  tag around the array, the array simply go outside my container, I had searched this type of question but didn't find it.

This is the code:

```
@if(count($elitePublications) > 0)
<div style="border:2px gold solid">
    @forelse($elitePublications as $key => $publication)
        @include('publications.small', compact('publication'))
    @empty
        <p></p>
    @endforelse
</div>
@endif
```

It only make the container but the list is outside

The code of publications.small:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 book">
<a href="{{ route('users.publications.show', ['publications'=>$publication->id, 'users'=>$publication->user->username]) }}"> 
    <div class="book-cover">
        {{ $publication->image }}
        <div class="inner-book-content">
            <h4>{{ $publication->published_book_title }}</h4>
             <strong class="book-price">
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `publications.small` outputting?  Maybe try a simpler test to make sure that `publications.small` isn't causing any issues.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones thanks for commenting, I added the code of `publication.small`

Comment: Nah, I just miss adding the last </div> but there it is... I think is something of bootstrap

Comment: what I would do to debug further is a simple version of what you have: `@forelse($elitePublications as $key => $publication)
content!
                @empty
                empty...
                @endforelse` This will help narrow down if HTML tags could be causing the issue or if it's something more related to the logic here.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Do I remove the <div> tags for the testing?

Comment: yes it wouldn't hurt to strip out all HTML when debugging to verify if your bug is related to the HTML tags or in the processing order in the loop

Comment: I found a path, will posted as answer but won't mark as correct, because I don't think its the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is about Bootstrap. Some kind of problem with the columns and the rows (who guest the results), so I just added a class in my div called "row" it act as a container for my array.

Like:

```
<div class="row">
    <h4 style="font-style: italic;"> Recomendados </h4>
    @forelse($elitePublications as $key => $publication)
        @include('publications.small', compact('publication'))
    @empty
    @endforelse
</div>
```